# How to create a strongly typed generic function for redux slices and their actions?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am using `@reduxjs/toolkit` and want to create an easily extendible function that creates a  slice with default reducers. The implementation that I have now works but is not strongly typed. How can I create a function so that the slice's actions type contains not only the default reducers but also the ones that are passed in? I have tried using inference types but could not get it to work.

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks.

Minimum example:
in `common.ts` file (where logic can be shared between slices)

```
export interface StoreState<T> {
  data: T
  status: 'succeeded' | 'failed' | 'idle'
  error: string | null
}

// create a slice given a name and make it possible to extend reducers so they include more than just reset and updateStatus
export const createStoreSlice = <T>(props: {
  sliceName: string
  defaultState: T
  reducers?: SliceCaseReducers<StoreState<T>> // <-- want to infer this in slices/<sliceName>.ts
}) => {
  const { sliceName, reducers, defaultState } = props

  const initialState: StoreState<T> = {
    data: defaultState,
    status: 'idle',
    error: null,
  }

  return createSlice({
    name: sliceName,
    initialState,
    reducers: {
      ...reducers, // <--- want to somehow infer the type of this when exporting slice actions
      reset: (state) => {
        Object.assign(state, initialState)
      },
      updateStatus: (state, action) => {
        state.status = action.payload
      },
    },
  })
}
```

in `slices/<sliceName>.ts` (specific slices with extra logic)

```
export const genericSlice = createStoreSlice({
  sliceName: 'someSliceName',
  defaultState: { someField: 'some value' },
  reducers: {
    setSomeField: (state, action) => {
      const { payload } = action
      state.data.someField = payload
    },
  },
})

// these actions should be strongly typed from the createStoreSlice function parameters and contain the default reducers (eg. reset, updateStatus) and extra ones specific to the slice (eg. setSomeField)
export const { reset, updateStatus, setSomeField } = genericSlice.actions
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were really close but there were three parts you were missing

1. You must infer the type of `reducers` with a generic type
2. You must use the generic `reducers` type (i.e. `R`) along with the provided `ValidateSliceCaseReducers` type to determine the resulting type for `reducers`.
3. Make `reducers` type required. I was only able to make it work with required reducers but there may be a way around this but unlikely as the types come from `@reduxjs/toolkit`.

> Note: I just pulled out the `createStoreSlice` props into the `StoreSliceProps` type to make it easier to read.

```
import { SliceCaseReducers, createSlice, ValidateSliceCaseReducers } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export interface StoreState<T> {
  data: T;
  status: 'succeeded' | 'failed' | 'idle';
  error: string | null;
}

interface StoreSliceProps<T, R extends SliceCaseReducers<StoreState<T>>> {
  sliceName: string;
  defaultState: T;
  reducers: ValidateSliceCaseReducers<StoreState<T>, R>;
}

export function createStoreSlice<T, R extends SliceCaseReducers<StoreState<T>>>(props: StoreSliceProps<T, R>) {
  const { sliceName, reducers, defaultState } = props;

  const initialState: StoreState<T> = {
    data: defaultState,
    status: 'idle',
    error: null,
  };

  return createSlice({
    name: sliceName,
    initialState,
    reducers: {
      ...reducers,
      reset: (state) => {
        Object.assign(state, initialState);
      },
      updateStatus: (state, action) => {
        state.status = action.payload;
      },
    },
  });
};

export const genericSlice = createStoreSlice({
  sliceName: 'someSliceName',
  defaultState: { someField: 'some value' },
  reducers: {
    setSomeField: (state, action) => {
      const { payload } = action;
      state.data.someField = payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { reset, updateStatus, setSomeField, fakeReducer } = genericSlice.actions; // only fakeReducer throws error as unknown as expected
```

Here is a working [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgZQDbAMYFMDCBDAZywCUsATAV2ygIBo4Mos8Ys1Mt6A1PdMltumz4ipStQJwAvnABmUCCDgByAAJNKADwBWBAPQwIEVAGtgMZQG4AUNaybIsOMAB2rKLLzYUhpshgCADwAKgB8iNZwcPwBAFxwwTZRBAEwFATxygRU2OTkynAAPiqewKj5RSrAZOVWkXBYUApQ8SlQrgDmlS4UqKg2Urau7p7e-tCCHAAKCmAEIfTEDZqsLmSS7MKEJORUjfPjfqlYIaFnEclCWAByeCBYrTDtLh1J0VievTD+AvGJ9Ro9jR4jw+AJNrhtmIgQdfGxjqdFqEBrZ7I54LIKC4MDBgBAXAwmOC4RCFnAlvZVusUFcRDtxPtAod4UEwmcABRgWYZHwTCEzCBzMnEUIASguDHxKUQcAIV1u93ogIk9DIHzwXx+rGkcAAvHAuYKCDZ6hgpfBXOZgLwtQ9eUdWeF9Qh6lEYnh4mrPqhvsdaK7Zal0plqrV-VEoo1mvEen1w9ITVEmGkoATGMxWBD2S6I3AXHc7XKOArOAHLbibX6A8r9vEc7m4AA6Zs1mjx3NMIgweLslICcW68L1htwADyACNtFgcY3CARgB0XL2-c4XFbK-23rmpO2IxQwDEWWkecuBPQvLj8QOhwHc33WI37+k9XAL3iXI2wHgAJ6oCB4MgtwjHcAxAqIpFFAYTTRaB4DNFxpQ6LAXEaTAIRfdNiT5K5s3qItsBLTICEUSYCILZR4y9DUfVtOtZRIgAxYAsFQMgiJIuAADdeAoLACjAuBWx5YdZSwb5GOY1ie3vThXxxd9rwlXN4OlJAv1-f8yB1fU33xIDkmORt3UfCSWK0-V1L-ACgIEkCIOghxYMlBD4CQTsxPofdDy1dJ6C7ZBTNY+hPBMekgW0uAkJQ9oMAhWd5KlSw4D0PQ4HxVBvzkPBQuhag4BgAALBQAHdJCjaBX0kLETBcCBioJQhljAadWDIIA)

See [this](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/a5cf61b366f23a868548d1ca7d56350c76610cbf/docs/usage/usage-with-typescript.md#wrapping-createslice) example from their docs that explains it a bit better.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! The TS playground doesn't seem to work. Would you be able to update it? Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry not sure how that got messed up. Try it now.